# Do we need injection (Dagger2 for example) between Model and Presenter in MVP structure?

Tags: android, code-injection, mvp, dagger

I know we can implement Dagger 2 to inject between Presenter and View layer, but do we need injection between M and P? Can you explain the reason?

Comment: AFAIK, dependency injection has nothing to do with the use of MVP. You can accomplish MVP with or without dependency injection.

Comment: @Karakuri I know. But I still don't understand whether it is better to use dependency injection between Model and Presenter.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the situation but generaly each layer should be independent of the others, so Presenter shouldn't be dependent on Model. So generally yes.

If you examine this very good example: 
https://medium.com/@nurrohman/a-simple-android-apps-with-mvp-dagger-rxjava-and-retrofit-4edb214a66d7#.89j5gtafn 
you will see that NetworkService (in this example is a class of Model layer) is injected into HomePresenter (a class of Presenter layer) by Dagger.

This example also confirms it:
https://github.com/grandstaish/hello-mvp-dagger-2

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am new to Dagger can't fully understand the example, I have another question, in order to make each layer independent, should I build 2 constructors for presenter? For presenter & view, presenter requires activity instance, for presenter & model, presenter requires result, is it reasonable to build such structure? Thank you!